# React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually react-native-webview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in ReactNative so I want to open a web view and i install WebView with following commands:

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
npx react-native link react-native-webview
```

now when I run this:

```
npx react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001
```

return to me this error :

> React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
>     - react-native-webview (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-webview")
>   This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
```

what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

React native 0.60 and above use autolinking. It mean you don’t need to link manually.

Now you have to unlink the lib

```
npx react-native unlink react-native-webview
```

Then

```
npx react-native run-android
```